# Count word frequency from multiple strings in dataframe column

Tags: r

I have a DF like the following with about 33000 rows:

```
tibble(ID = c(1,2,3), desc = c("This is a description.", "Also a description!","This is yet another desciption"))
```

I would like to count every word for all rows, to get a resulting df like:

```
tibble(word = c("this", "is", "a", "description", "also", "yet", "another"), count = c(2,2,2,3,1,1,1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several textmining packages available. tidytext, quanteda, tm, ...

Below an example using tidytext.

```
library(tibble)

df1 <- tibble(ID = c(1,2,3), desc = c("This is a description.", "Also a description!","This is yet another desciption"))

library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)

df1 %>% 
  unnest_tokens(words, desc) %>% 
  group_by(words) %>% 
  count(words)

# A tibble: 8 x 2
# Groups:   words [8]
  words           n
  <chr>       <int>
1 a               2
2 also            1
3 another         1
4 desciption      1
5 description     2
6 is              2
7 this            2
8 yet             1
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be something like

```
table(unlist(strsplit(paste(collection_df$desc), "\\W")))
```

It is hard to answer your question as you did not provide clear problem, example and your expected output.